# Flutter dynamic Dismissible height with ExpansionTile

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I have `Dismissible` with `ExpansionTile` as a child. Is there any way to make `Dismissible` be flexible in height? For now it has static height, but should have child's height

Answer (score 0):

Within a Column (for flexible height), you can use a Flexible, with fit:FlexFit.loose, This will size to the child.